# How can I compress video by taking advantage of its static content?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, video-encoding, video-codecs

I have an HD video that is a presentation, so it consists mostly of still images. It's a 50 minute, 200MB MP4 file, downloaded from YouTube.

Is there a way to take advantage of the static nature of the content to compress it further?

Comment: When you encode to MP4 using FFmpeg/x264, the encoder flags duplicate frames and writes a minimal packet for that frame, around 30-40 **bytes**.

Comment: @Mulvya I downloaded that video from Youtube using Youtube-dl. I'm not sure how it's encoded. I used settings from your answer and reduced file size to half without any visible quality loss.

Comment: You can increase CRF value for a greater reduction. Say, upto 27.

Comment: Is the video a direct screen capture, or a camera recording?

Comment: @grawity screen capture. Audio is at 192k, so around 68MB and video is 130MB together 198MB. Video is already encoded using x265.

Comment: Youtube already uses advanced compression algorithms

Comment: As @Gantendo said, a 50 minute HD video with *only*(!) 200MB is extremely compact already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a command-line tool,

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -crf 23 -preset slow -b:a 96k out.mp4
```

Comment: Is there any without changing bitrate or losing quality. The video mostly has still images. So video has same frame for like 3 mins. Currently testing with one video, I will get back to you.

Comment: You could try identifying the bitrate using `mediainfo` and then using that as your ffmpeg preset. By definition, you're re-encoding the video, so you're going to lose some quality.

Comment: Bitrate = how many bits a second of source material occupies. Your goal here is to reduce bitrate without loosing quality. If you won't change bitrate and video length, you'll get the same size.

Comment: Assuming 24 FPS and HD resolution (1280x720) with 8-bit RGB color that would be 66GB of uncompressed data after 50 minutes.  So those 200MB are already only 0.3% of the original data. I doubt you can reduce that any further without loosing details.